# How to restrict a specific user to an IP range he can login from?

Tags: users

I want to create a subscription service where the user can only login with the IP address the user registered with and all Class C & D's of that IP range. How can this be done?

Would also be great if I can restrict the user to logging in from withing that state if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at [IP Ranges](http://drupal.org/project/ip_ranges) module.

> IP Ranges is a module that let's you completely ban both single IP-addresses as well as
>   full ranges from your site. The ban is triggered already at the early bootstrap phase, so you
>   can get rid of unwanted visitors as early as possible without wasting server resources.
>
> You can also define whitelists that override blacklists, both single and ranged.
>   The UI is similar to core ip-ban, so you will feel like home immediately.